# Typescript: Why this generic function throws error in strict mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop

I have to difference classes named `Bird` and `Cow` with no relations between them. I want to create a function to fetch my desired model. A function like this:

```js
const birdModel = getModel(AnimalType.BIRD);
```

I wanted it to be typesafe and it works, It resolves the correct type when I use IDE to check its type however the `getModel` function itself has error

```
Type 'BirdModel' is not assignable to type 'AnimalTypeToModelMap[K]'.
  Type 'BirdModel' is not assignable to type 'BirdModel & CowModel'.
    Property 'cowName' is missing in type 'BirdModel' but required in type 'CowModel'.ts(2322)
```

This is my code:

```js
class BirdModel {
    birdName: string = 'bird';
}

class CowModel {
    cowName: string = 'cow';
}

enum AnimalType {
    BIRD,
    COW
}

type AnimalTypeToModelMap = {
    [AnimalType.BIRD]: BirdModel;
    [AnimalType.COW]: CowModel;
}

function getModel<K extends keyof AnimalTypeToModelMap>(type: K): AnimalTypeToModelMap[K] {
    if (type === AnimalType.BIRD) {
        return new BirdModel;
    } else if (type === AnimalType.COW) {
        return new CowModel;
    } else {
        throw new Error('unable to find model');
    }
}


function sayIt<K extends keyof AnimalTypeToModelMap>(type: K) {
  const model = getModel(type);
  if (model.cowName) {
    console.log(model.cowName);
  }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You first need to fix the fact that you are apparently returning constructors when you are claiming to return instances.  If you want constructors, then `AnimalTypeToModelMap`'s property types should be `typeof BirdModel` and `typeofCowModel` instead of `BirdModel` and `CowModel`.  If you want instances, then your implementation of `getModel()` needs `return new BirdModel();` and `return new CowModel()` instead of `return BirdModel` and `return CowModel`.  Your issue will remain, but at least it will be what you're saying it is.

Comment: Does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mA7XBw) meet your needs?  If not, please elaborate on what the issue is.  If so, let me know and I'd be happy to write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks it works until you want to use it from another function, Please check main post I updated it again

Comment: There are now a number of errors in your code, and they are caused by different issues (type parameter narrowing, generic value narrowing, indexing into unions). I could resolve all of them [with this refactoring](https://tsplay.dev/wOaYzm); does that meet your needs?  I would prefer to focus any answer on a particular issue rather than a list of different problems that all happen to be present in a single example; could you modify this code to be a [mcve] of just one issue?  Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz Your example is valid however it requires at least TypeScript 4.3 but it is beta and I can't comment on it until my environment also get updated to it. But seems to solve my issue.